# Split Elixir List into Equal Chunks

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a list that might contain as many as 100K Contacts, How can i effectlively split this list into batches of 100.

I've tried

```
Enum.chunk(phonebook_contacts,100,100,[]),
```

but somehow it appears there appears to be duplicates in the individual lists.

As a more complete snippet, i've got something like this

```
for x <- Enum.chunk(phonebook_contacts,100,100,[]) do
for y <- x do    
unless Telephony.user_balance_account_number(account_number) <= 0 do
Task.start_link(fn -> 
# Do some background stuff with y
receive do
{:fs_job_result, job_id, packet}-> Telephony.alter_campaign_stats(packet.custom_payload,campaign_id)
after
500000 ->
 IO.puts  "No message in 10 seconds"
end
 end)
...
```

Is there a better approach than using Enum.chunk ? and avoid the duplicates?

Comment: So your original list doesn't have duplicates but after `Enum.chunk` it has duplicates?

Comment: @Dogbert, the Original list does not have duplicates. After Enum.chunk, some duplicates tend to appear

Comment: Are you sure about that? `Enum.chunk` when called with equal values for `count` and `step` should not give you duplicates.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1` effectively accepts chained accumulators, hence two subsequent `for`s are redundant. Use: `for x <- Enum.chunk(...), y <- x do` instead.

Comment: @Dogbert, after further investigations, the duplicates were not from the elixir side of things. Occurred at a 3rd party's end after the list has been passed on. At least i learnt how to refactor `for`